# apex trigger to prevent for a defined account recordType to record more than one contact (without creating a custom field for Contact)

Tags: apex, trigger

As stated I'm trying to write an Apex Trigger to limit for **only** a specific recordType of Account for example 'Customer' to only be able to add one and only one Contact to the Account if there is not contact.
Otherwise i need to throw an error as a Contact is already registered for that account where recordType is 'Customer'.

Plus, I'm trying to do that without using and creating a custom field in the sObject account such as 'Type__c' and use something like (to achieve that) :

```
Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypesMap =
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();


    
List<Contact> getOneContactExpected = [SELECT ID, AccountId FROM Contact where AccountId in: accountIdSet AND contact.account.recordTypeId in : recordTypesMap.get('Customer')];

 if (getOneContactExpected.size()>0) {
            //add the contact
        } else {
            //throw an error .addError
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the typical [Aggregate-Query-Update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) to gather the values we want to query, perform that query, then perform updates based on those results.

First, we get all of the Account Ids that might be involved:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
}
accountIds.remove(null); // Ignore contacts with no account
```

Then, we use a favorite trick of mine where we use `new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([seom query]).keySet()` to get all of the Id values out of an aggregate result without the need for a for loop:

```
Set<Id> overLimit = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT AccountId Id 
    FROM Contact 
    WHERE AccountId = :accountIds AND 
        Account.RecordType.Name = 'Customer'
    GROUP BY AccountId
    HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
]).keySet();
```

By aliasing a lookup field to `Id`, the constructor is able to extract the Id values as keys, which we then take out of the map by using `keySet()`. The HAVING keyword returns groups that match a given criteria; this one matches if there are more than one contact for a given AccountId.

Finally, we go over the list of contact records and add an error to any where the AccountId appears; they are contacts belonging to accounts with more than one contact and are Customer record type accounts.

```
for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    if(overLimit.contains(record.AccountId)) {
        record.AccountId.addError('You may not add more than one contact to a Customer Account.');
    }
}
```

---

So, putting it all together, we get the final version that looks something like:

```
trigger on limitCustomerCount on Contact(after insert, after update) {
    //////// Aggregate
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
    }
    accountIds.remove(null);
    //////// Query
    Set<Id> overLimit = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
        SELECT AccountId Id 
        FROM Contact 
        WHERE AccountId = :accountIds AND 
            Account.RecordType.Name = 'Customer'
        GROUP BY AccountId
        HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
    ]).keySet();
    //////// Update
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        if(overLimit.contains(record.AccountId)) {
            record.AccountId.addError('You may not add more than one contact to a Customer Account.');
        }
    }
}
```

---

This solution assumes you do not have "Relate Contacts to multiple Accounts" enabled in your org. If so, you'll need to have a trigger on the AccountContactRelation instead. The principles would be the same as this version, but for AccountContactRelation objects instead.